# CakePHP 1.2 custom label for form helper input

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am editing views/elements/form_user.ctp and require a custom label for my input, I cannot change the current value from city to say city/town because this value must correspond to the database field.

My code is currently:

```
 echo $form->input('city');
```

How do I add a custom label to the form helper to display a customised label that doesn't output text as exactly the name of the database field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $form->input('city', array(
  'label' => 'My Label'
));
```

It's in the [docs](http://api12.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput)...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/view/189/Automagic-Form-Elements) as this is pretty basic stuff imho!

```
echo $form->input('city', array('label' => 'My Field'));
```